# SKSpriteNode will not appear when its physics body is dynamic

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, physics, skspritenode

The SKSprite will only appear on the scene if `.isDynamic = false` otherwise it will not show up. Although it does not show up, it seems to be contacting with the other nodes in the scene.

I have tried playing around with the x and y values of the "lemming" node but this still results in it not appearing.

**The Question:**

> What do I need to add or remove in order to make the "lemming" node be affected
>   by gravity, appear in the scene, and contact correctly with the "cliff" node?

In the GameScene.swift file:

```
//MARK: - Nodes
    var background = SKSpriteNode()
    var cliff = SKTexture()
    var lemming = SKSpriteNode()

    //MARK: -Catergories
    let lemmingCatergory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    let cliffCatergory   : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2

    //MARK: - Start of game functions
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        scaleMode = .aspectFit
        size = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -9.81)
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        addBackground()
        addCliff()
        addLemming()
        view.showsPhysics = true
    }

    //MARK: -Node customization
    private func addBackground() {
        background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
        background.name = "Background"
        background.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
        background.size = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        background.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: background.frame.size)
        background.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        background.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        addChild(background)
    }

    private func addCliff() {
        var cliffNode : SKSpriteNode!
        cliff = SKTexture(imageNamed: "cliff")
        cliffNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: cliff)
        cliffNode.name = "Cliff"
        cliffNode.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
        cliffNode.size = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        cliffNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: cliff, size: cliff.size())
        cliffNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = cliffCatergory
        cliffNode.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = lemmingCatergory
        cliffNode.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = lemmingCatergory
        cliffNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        cliffNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        cliffNode.physicsBody?.pinned = true
        cliffNode.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        addChild(cliffNode)
    }

    private func addLemming() {
        lemming = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "lemming")
        lemming.size = CGSize(width: lemming.size.width / 15, height: lemming.size.height / 15)
        lemming.position = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
        lemming.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: lemming.frame.size)
        lemming.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = lemmingCatergory
        lemming.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = cliffCatergory
        lemming.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = cliffCatergory
        lemming.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        lemming.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        addChild(lemming)
    }

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("Body A: \(String(describing: contact.bodyA.node!.name))")
        print("Body B: \(String(describing: contact.bodyB.node!.name))")
    }
```

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but it’s not appearing and then almost instantly falling through the bottom of the screen due to gravity, is it?

Comment: @SteveIves That could very likely be the case. I turned on the physics bounds for the scene and you can see something slide down the right side of the screen. But then it makes contact with the cliff node and seems to stay on the screen.